# Is it possible to estimate how much Plutonium existed during the earth's formation?

Tags: isotope, transuranic-elements

Plutonium is a man-made element, but minute quantities of it exist on earth. It's probable the earth had much larger quantities of it during its formation as a planet, but most of it decayed due to its half-life. In the same vein (no pun intended) as carbon-14 dating, is it possible to determine how much of it existed by determining if some of the radionuclides on earth are remaining products of its decay chain?

In other words, can we study uranium, lead, thallium, bismuth, etc. samples on earth and determine if they were transmuted from plutonium?

Comment: It could be interesting to compare the amount of Pu thought to be present in the Earth at 'birth' and the amount produced during natural reactors such as Oklo (estimated to be about 2 tons of Pu-239).

Comment: So do radionuclides have any signature that can be used to determine their previous decay state? Interestingly, the common Pu-239 isn't the longest lived isotope.

Comment: I think this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium#Occurrence answers it.

Comment: The country of Gabon should make Oklo a nuclear tourism destination with a centrifuge amusement park ride and concession stands serving glow-in-the-dark Cherenkov drinks and hot yellow cakes. Great way to boost their economy. LOL!